# problem forwarding USB device to virtual box

Tags: 12.04, usb, virtualbox

I want to connect a CAN to USB interface for programming an engine control unit to a WinXP virtual machine.
only this device is not listed in under the small USB Icon at the lower left of the vm window.

running usb-devices I get the following info:

```
T:  Bus=06 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=00 MxPS=16 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0000 ProdID=0102 Rev=01.00
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

My VM works with all other usb devices (including some unusual ones). The device thats not working on my system is working fine with virtualbox on a Mac and a BSD host my colleges laptops.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and virtualbox 4.1.18

Thanks in advance this would really make my work a lot easier, not having to boot win all the time :-(

additional info:

This is what happens when I plug in the device in question:

```
udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[13416.745162] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.745212] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.745236] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.745265] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.745287] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.745309] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.745330] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.745352] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.745782] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.747609] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.747653] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.747680] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.747705] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.748618] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.748830] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.749363] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.750026] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.750062] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.750086] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.750115] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.751381] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.751417] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.751443] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.751898] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753027] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753050] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753064] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753077] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753091] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753105] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753118] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753132] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753145] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753158] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753171] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.753184] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.755131] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.755158] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.755174] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.755189] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.755203] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.755218] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.755231] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.755245] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.755260] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.755275] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.755289] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.755303] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.755622] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.755643] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.755656] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
KERNEL[13416.755670] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759319] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759348] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759364] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759379] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759394] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759409] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759424] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759439] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state3 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759453] remove   /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759468] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpuidle/state2 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759482] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1 (cpu)
UDEV  [13416.759496] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0 (cpu)
KERNEL[13417.205442] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1 (usb)
KERNEL[13417.208418] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [13417.227113] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1 (usb)
UDEV  [13417.229757] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6/6-1/6-1:1.0 (usb)
```

and this is what happens if i plug in the Vector device that is forwarded correctly:

```
udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[13696.085406] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2 (usb)
KERNEL[13696.465828] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [13696.484915] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2 (usb)
UDEV  [13696.492091] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
```

output from lsusb:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:1004 Lenovo Integrated Webcam
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 08ff:2810 AuthenTec, Inc. AES2810
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0a5c:2145 Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth with Enhanced Data Rate II
Bus 006 Device 007: ID 0000:0102  
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 1248:1001
```

tail -f /var/log/kern.log including connecting and diconnecting the device:

```
tp@tp-ThinkPad-R500:~$ tail -f /var/log/kern.log
Jul 15 10:46:53 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15135.583561] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
Jul 15 10:46:53 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15135.632544] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jul 15 10:46:53 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15135.633620] tg3 0000:04:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X
Jul 15 10:46:53 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15135.662314] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jul 15 10:46:55 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15137.314088] tg3 0000:04:00.0: eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
Jul 15 10:46:55 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15137.314093] tg3 0000:04:00.0: eth0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
Jul 15 10:46:55 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15137.315407] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jul 15 10:46:56 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15138.477486] input: Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/input14
Jul 15 10:46:56 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15138.477699] generic-bluetooth 0005:046D:B009.0002: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v4.16 Mouse [Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b] on 00:24:2C:BF:81:72
Jul 15 10:47:05 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15148.080037] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Jul 15 10:52:03 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15445.116070] usb 6-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using uhci_hcd
Jul 15 10:52:16 tp-ThinkPad-R500 kernel: [15458.488118] usb 6-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
```

Comment: Do you see it under Ubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean by "see"? It is listed in "usb-devices".

Answer (score 2):

Its probably a problem with VB usb support in Ubuntu

Install the USB 2.0 support as said before https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

But then add your user to *vboxusers* group https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB

Its a common problem in VB to not have privileges to USB in the vboxusers

```
sudo adduser yourusername vboxusers
```

Sadly, after adding to the group you need to log out and log in, then try again, VB should recognize the USB in the list

(In the last versions is not even needed to add the filter, you just open the "USB Devices" menu on the running VM and select the device and in would plug in on the client machine)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the `virtualbox extension pack`

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

and you also want to install the `guest additions` to get the appropriate drivers for your virtualbox client.

Comment: installed the extension pack => no difference; reinstalled guest  => no difference

Comment: install the guest additions too, after that access the USB panel as pictured in the image in the other post

Comment: guest additions was also installed, I already see for USB devices in the VM (3 internals of my Laptop one external) but not the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Some USB devices may not work properly with Virtual Box. This may be the case with your CAN to USB interface but it is worth to try out if we get Virtual Box to access it.

To do so we may try to add an *"empty"* USB filter in the USB settings of your machine:

[image]

This may already help recognizing your device. We may also try to further specify USB properties on a right click on the *"New Filer 1"* to open a settings window with some explanatory tooltips for each entry:

[image]

Read also the [Virtual Box manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp13237504) for an explanation of these settings and how to get them.

Comment: tried a specific filter using the VendorID=0000 and ProdID = 0102 => no difference; a blank filter forwards my fingerprint sensor and an USB device from [vector](http://www.vector.com/vi_vn1600_en.html) already used earlier in the vm.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you have checked the `Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller` checkmark shown in Takkat's response ?
Furthermore, it may be useful to see what is happening to the USB device when you plug it into  your computer. With this in mind, the following commands may help you to develop more information

```
lsusb
udev monitor
```

It is possible that you will need to create udev rules for the device in order to ensure that it is owned by an appropriate group. It may be helpful to know more about the device that you are using.

Comment: "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" was checked. The Problem is that I dont know anything about the device. It comes with the ECU and is only meant to program the ECUs made by [EFI](http://www.obr.uk.com/efi_engine_mngt.html). I only know that EFI buys the CANtoUSB device form some other company. It works fine with WinXP and Win7.

Comment: Alright, then lets go at this in a broad sense to start with. Detach the device, open a terminal, and run the command
`tail -f /var/log/kern.log` then plug the device back in and watch how the kernel responds to the device, should be several lines of output. Copy that and let see what it says

Comment: added the kern.log in the question